# Configuring ember-simple-auth with ember-cli-simple-auth-token

Tags: javascript, authentication, ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I would like to use ember-simple-auth with ember-cli-simple-auth-token , for this, i installed and put in my configs:

```
  ENV['simple-auth-token'] = {
    identificationField: 'email',
    serverTokenEndpoint: 'http://localhost:3000/token'
  };
```

But i keep seen this message:

```
No authorizer was configured for Ember Simple Auth - specify one if backend requests need to be authorized.
```

I installed:

```
ember install ember-cli-simple-auth
ember install ember-cli-simple-auth-token
```

Then generate:

ember g simple-auth-token
ember g simple-auth-token

Am i missing some configuration?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to configure:

```
ENV['simple-auth'] = {
  authorizer: 'simple-auth-authorizer:token'
}
```

You should also keep in mind that you've installed a deprecated version of Simple Auth. You should be using `ember-simple-auth` now.

Comment: should i generate something??